# Two bootable partitions using same secondary internal hard drive

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, filesystems

I have a computer with two internal hard drives, one of which I boot windows off of, the other I store files in. Could I create a Linux partition on my first drive, and have both operating systems access the second drive's files? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/95254/how-to-access-ubuntu-files-from-windows-on-a-dual-boot-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Question:

> Could I create a Linux partition on my first drive

If you have enough free space left on the disk, the windows partition is on.
If you have a single partition disk you first need to [resize it](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) in windows to create some free space.

Most user-friendly Linux distributions with desktops like Ubuntu give you the option, during the installation, to create the operation system on a separate partition so you can continue to use the Windows one without having the need of knowledge in creating partitions and file-systems.

The problem left is that the BIOS (I assume you are using BIOS as firmware) can't read partitions. You can only select the storage device to boot from. Then the standard partition-table (Master-Boot-record) points towards the partition to boot from. The Master-Boot-Record can only point towards one partition. Means you can't have a multiboot system.

I know that Ubuntu (and some other inc: Debian) automatically replace (during the installation) the MBR with the GUID-Partition-Table and add Grub as boot loader. Grub sees multiple os installations on multiple partitions inside the disk that was select from BIOS and offers you a list to choose from during startup.

You need to find out if the operation system you are planning to install does this process on its own. If not: you have to manually install gpt and grub then install the os.

Second question:

> have both operating systems access the second drive's files

Easily. In almost all Linux distros recognized filesystems inside /dev  get showed inside the file-manager and can be mounted/unmounted with one click. I assume the Filesystem on the storage disk is Fat32?

Comment: No problem ^^ did it help you out completely? If anything else is you can ask :)